# C# - storing objects drawn by graphicsObject

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

Im using `System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj` for drawing objects on `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`. What is wise method to store informations about old drawings? To remove last drawing during MouseMove event?

Do i have to remember Pen settings and cords?

Thanks :)

// edit. I think my question is not clear. I have a Panel. I treat it like a container for drawing.

I can draw multiple lines, circles, rectangles.

Every time i press the mouse (MouseDown), im want to start drawing new object. When i move mouse (MouseMove), object currently drawed has to change (for example line, like in paint). When i release the mouse (MouseUp), i want object i drawed to became constant.

Now, i tried to invoke `graphicsObj.Clear();` method on MouseMove event, but it clears all drawed objects.

So i deduced, that i have to store informations about old drawed objects. And now, i have to make lists (vectors or so) and store informations about that objects? Or there is a method to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle all painting in the `Panel`'s `Paint` event, that is exactly what it's there for.

The `Paint` event gives you in its `PaintEventArgs` the `Graphics` object you should use. This will make sure your instructions are painted on every refresh, not just once.

If you are deriving from `Panel`, override the `OnPaint` method instead.

**Edit after original question has been expanded:**

You should separate the logic of storing the data from the logic of displaying your data. The `Graphics` object's purpose is to display existing data, not to store data.

I think making `List`s or other collection of the objects you are drawing is the best solution.
You will also need flags to handle all the logic of what is a "live" object, etc.

Comment: I updated my queston (better explaination). I dont know if this is what i need.

Comment: Ok, i understand :) In onPaint method iterate trough objects and draw, in mouse events just add objects to list and request repaint.

Comment: Exactly. The way to request a repaint is using `Invalidate()`, or the more immediate `Refresh()`. You should read about those two methods and their overloads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store your last x,y into an array of Points objects as history.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what you are after here, but if you want some sort of memory about what paint drew.
Draw to a collections of bitmaps, then have your paint routine draw one of the bitmaps on to the control.

Comment: I explained it better, if you have a time and will, you can look again :)